# How can I change Color of a <td> with a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

How can I change the color of a `<td>` element based on the value of a radio button? I would like to set `<td bgcolor></td>` to red if the radio button is checked "NO" and to green if  the radio button is checked "OK".

```
function color(){
  if(radio1.checked()){
    td1.bgcolor="green";
  }
  if(radio2.checked()){
    td1.bgcolor="red";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#B35556">
      <form action="">
        OK <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"value="OK" checked="color()"/> <BR>
        NO  <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2"value="NO"/>                
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I Know that this code is very wrong but it's an example to make you understand my question

Comment: A radio button is a native element specific to each OS/browser. There is no way to change its color/style, unless you want to implement custom images or use a custom Javascript library which includes images

Comment: i must change the color of a <td> and not the radio !

Comment: yeah you can do that,  td color can be change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few points:

1. Define radio buttons as part of the same group with the name property (radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group).
2. Attach the function to the `onchage` event of both the radio buttons.
3. You have to use element's `style` property to set the `backgroundColor`.

Try the following way:

```js
function color(el){
  if(el.value=="OK"){
    el.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="green";
  }
  else{
    el.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#B35556">
      <form action="">

        OK <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1"value="OK" onchange="color(this)"/> <BR>
        NO <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"value="NO" onchange="color(this)" checked/>

      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This one is prefered since OP did not clarify the need of jQuery. Good old DOM

Comment: Good lightweight solution +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript `change` event to run your code on raido button change. In event listener check state and value of target radio to setting background color.

```js
$(":radio").change(function(){      
    if (this.checked && this.value == "OK")
        $(this).closest("td").css("background", "green");
    else if (this.checked && this.value == "NO")
        $(this).closest("td").css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#B35556">
      <form action="">    
      OK <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="OK"/> 
      <br>
      NO <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" value="NO" checked />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also you do this work using simple code:

```
$(":radio").change(function(){      
  if (this.checked)
      $(this).closest("td").css("background", this.value=="OK" ? "green" : "red");      
});
```

Comment: And in addition to this you could start with a **checked** attribute on **no**. Make sure the first background-color of your td is red in that case. Just one remark. This is jQuery. It is also possible to do this with an **element.style.backgroundColor** value

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a variable along with the function call on the Ui

For example:

```
<form action="">
   OK <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"value="OK" checked="color('ok')"/> <BR>
   NO  <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2"value="NO" checked="color('no')"/>
```

Then in your Javascript you can catch the string and check for it's contents:

```
function color(CB) {
         var TEMP = CB;
         if(TEMP == 'ok') {
            td1.bgcolor="green";
         }
         else if(TEMP == 'no'){
            td1.bgcolor="red";
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function color()
{
 
  if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked)
  {
  document.getElementById("td1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
 
  }
  if(document.getElementById("radio2").checked)
  {
 document.getElementById("td1").style.backgroundColor = "#B35556";
  }
 }
```

```html
<body>
<table>

<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#B35556" id="td1">
  <form action="">
    

       OK <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"value="OK" onclick="color()"/> <BR>
        NO  <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2"value="NO" onclick="color()" checked>
       
   
  </form>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```